# MySQL Transport Protocol Used

Tags: mysql, protocol

How can I find out which Transport Protocol MySQL is using? I know how I can [change it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connection-options.html#option_general_protocol) but I don't know how to show the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two passive ways to find that out

1. Connection Status
2. MySQL Prompt

### EXAMPLE

If you execute the status command (`\s`)

```
mysql> \s
```

you get this output

```
MySQL://localhost/root/mysqld.sock/(none)> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:          3
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.7.26 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    latin1
Conn.  characterset:    latin1
UNIX socket:            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 10 min 57 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 24  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 109  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 28  Queries per second avg: 0.036
--------------

MySQL://localhost/root/mysqld.sock/(none)>
```

Just under `Protocol version`, you see how I am connected:

```
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
```

Another method would be to look at your MySQL prompt, provided you configured the prompt display. Please note my current prompt:

```
MySQL://localhost/root/mysqld.sock/(none)>
```

I have it set in `.my.cnf` under the `[mysql]` group header

```
[mysql]
prompt="MySQL://\h/\u/\p/\d> "
```

The `\h` echoes the host address and `\p` echoes the port number in use. in my case, since it echoes `localhost` and `mysqld.sock` , it is not using TCP/IP. If it were using TCP/IP, it should echo `127.0.0.1` and `3306`.

If you want to try connect with TCP/IP, you have to use [--protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connection-options.html#option_general_protocol) as you mentioned:

```
#> mysql -h127.0.0.1 --protocol=tcp -uroot -p
```

Comment: when you use -h 127.0.1.1 you get always the tcpip even without the .p

Comment: I prefer to write the status command as `status`, it's more mnemonic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a variable for that.

As it makes basically no different, if you use on a local machine (names pipes windows only / Sockets linux only ) or tcp/ip.

When you try to connect from another machine you can use only tcp/ip

When you connect to a local host with `-h localhost` then the client will first try to use names pipes/sockets and  when that fails it will try tcp/ip.

If you connect with `-h 127.0.0.1` the client will use only tcp/ip